# List of link types in Boomla?

Tags: boomla

Is there a list of all currently available link types in Boomla?
I could not find it in the documentation.

https://boomla.com/docs/api-reference/file-types/deprecated-types/sjs-3/file/properties/link says "see the filesystem specification for details" - but I don't know where the specification is.

As far as I know, there is

- package (but it was called import berore?)
- volume
- scope
- db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it on the [File link](https://boomla.com/docs/how-it-works/anatomy-of-the-boomla-filesystem/file-link) docs page. I agree it should be in the API reference too, will add it there.

There is no `db` link, it was only planned but not yet implemented. Yes the `import` link was renamed to `package` link.